# C++ programs do not get focus when started from launcher in Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, c++

My C++ programs run fine in a terminal on Xubuntu 13.10. But when they are started from a launcher, then they do not get focus. The focus remains with the desktop. These programs use the grab_focus method for entry fields. That works if they run in a terminal. But not from a launcher. What must I do to make these programs get focus immediately when the launcher is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. If the **Use startup notification** checkbox (shown in image below) in the launcher is checked, then this happens. You can access the menu to edit the launchers by right-clicking on the Xubuntu button and selecting **Edit Menus**

[image]

Comment: Can you add details on _use startup notification_. Where actually that settings resides?